# Nautilus (11.10), getting the old icon-list-small menu back on panel?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

After upgrade to 11.10 the menu for changing folder view has gone. Now you have to go through the mainmenu -> View.

I switch back and forth list / icon view a lot, so i really want that shothand menu back.

It seems not to be an option in Nautilus preferences, and there is no entry for it in dconf-editor -> org.gnome.nautilus either.

Is this "feature" for some obscure reason completely gone?

Comment: One more reason to install cinnamon over ubuntu. If you are willing to change your whole desktop appearance give it a look.

Comment: I'm very tempted. I used half a day getting rid of all the unity "features" - does cinnamon work with a "classic" setup?

Answer (score 0):

About Cinnamon and features that you might like.

It is level up from the classic gnome, much better in my opinion.

- You get normal desktop bars, very nicely configurable.
- It has Nemo instead of Nautilus, they are quite similar and will guive you that list menu you are looking for;
- Menus don't have the same look but the structure is close from the classic one you areused to;
- One down point is that compiz will not work, although some of the desktop related features are automatically implemented. The feature that I miss the most is the grid;
- Applets and screenlets are  available online and easy to install, just copy past folder;
- You can configure almost everything by right clicking on it.

Here is a review about it,
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-cinnamon.html